# Display list of images using XML

Tags: html, xml

I'm trying to figure out how I can display a list the list of `<images>` in `<imgurl>` from the XML file below.

XML DATA:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<stock>
            <dealer>
                            <dealername>Car Dealer Name</dealername>
                            <dealerID>99</dealerID>

                                            <vehicle>
                                              <stockID>11111</stockID>
                                              <make>VW</make>
                                              <model>Touareg </model>
                                              <images>
                                                            <imgurl>URL1</imgurl>
                                                            <imgurl>URL2</imgurl>
                                                            <imgurl>URL3</imgurl>
                                                            <imgurl>URL4</imgurl>


                                              </images>    
                                            </vehicle>
  </dealer>
 </stock>
```

In the XSLT page I have the following:

```
<xsl:for-each select="stock/dealer/vehicle">
<div class="main-image">
<img src="{images/imgurl}" />
</div>
<xsl:copy>
  <img>  <xsl:attribute name="src">  <xsl:value-of select="images"/> </xsl:attribute></img>
</xsl:copy>

                  <div>
                    <h3><xsl:value-of select="make"/>  &nbsp; <xsl:value-of select="model"/> </h3>


                  </div>  
</xsl:for-each>
```

Without `<img>  <xsl:attribute name="src">`  it displays the text of all the URLs but not the images. With the attributes nothing is displayed (only a single broken image icon). I need to display all the images.

Hope this is clear.

Comment: Provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You questions does not show what you are doing. Which tool do you use for the transformation?

Comment: I have updated the question. hope it makes sense

Comment: V in MCVE means verifiable. And verifiable means, that everybody who reads the question should be able to reproduce the error. Is the information in your question sufficient, so that everybody can reproduce the error? No it is not. The question is tagged with "javascript", but does not contain any JavaScript code. So either add the code or remove the tag.